# Синтаксическая омонимия

Tags: синтаксис

Есть определение «Происшествие без последствий». Его употребляют в вопросительном предложении «Произошло ли происшествие без последствий?»

Является ли этот случай синтаксической омонимией? Или нужно обособить данное определение в кавычки?

Comment: Нужно говорить по-русски:  Происшествие не имело последствий?

Comment: С кавычками стилистическая ошибка (неблагозвучие, громоздкость), без кавычек лексическая ошибка (неправильное использование глагола произойти вместо оказаться). Оказалось ли происшествие без последствий? Звучит не очень, но без лексической ошибки.